# Send newline through serial monitor

Tags: serial

I know I can send a newline using the option in the bottom right:

[image]

But why doesnt it work to use the option 'No line ending', and send a '\n' or '\r\n' after the text using the arduino serial monitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslash escape encoding for special characters is a feature of double quotes in some programming languages, shells, and other parsers.  It is not normally a feature of live text input - an "end user" human typing a backslash is assumed to mean it literally.

"Live" input of a carriage return or newline is more traditionally done with the return/enter key, or with the corresponding control codes - CTRL-J for newline and/or CTRL-M for return.  I don't know that the Arduino IDE's Serial Monitor supports either of these, at least once you select "no line ending"